# How to nest select statements in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to select only the `User_IDs` that are in the first select statement and the last select statement, but I am doing something wrong.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) AS total
FROM UserClicks
WHERE (Date > :startDate AND Date < :endDate) 
AND User_ID IN (
    SELECT User_ID 
    FROM UserClicks
    WHERE (Date > :monthBeforeStartDate AND Date < :startDate)
)
```

**Update:** This is for a MySQL database.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  SQL syntax varies by system.

Comment: can you post the table structure please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub-query and join will suit you here

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.UserID 
FROM
  UserClicks u1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT 
      UserID 
   FROM 
     UserClicks 
   WHERE 
     (Date > :monthBeforeStartDate AND Date < :startDate)
) u2
ON u1.UserID = u2.UserID
WHERE
  (u1.Date > :startDate AND u1.Date < :endDate)
```

Comment: Couldn't you explain the query a little? I need to do a slightly different select - and I'm not even sure if this is the way or not.

Answer (score 0):

if your query is hanging, it's because of indexing, to optimize the outer query and inner query, you'd want indexes like so:

```
create index du on UserClicks (Date, User_ID)
create index ud on UserClicks (User_ID, Date)
```

it should then return instantly. more details on how mysql optimizes sub queries specified with the `IN` operator:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizing-subqueries.html

> MySQL replaces subqueries of the
>   following form with an index-lookup
>   function, which EXPLAIN describes as a
>   special join type (unique_subquery or
>   index_subquery):
>
> ... IN (SELECT indexed_column FROM
>   single_table ...)

Comment: It looks like a query to "get users who clicked between start and end who also clicked the month prior".  
  
So they can indeed be both < startDate and > startDate.

Comment: Heh, and you just deleted the part of your answer I commented on.

Comment: adding some_name at the end did not fix the problem.

Comment: error, haven't been able to retrieve any results yet, it just hangs

Comment: mysql sometimes does that, if you `create index du on (Date, User_ID);` and `create index ud on (User_ID, Date);` it should return instantly (some info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimizing-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) AS total
    FROM UserClicks
    WHERE (Date BETWEEN startDate AND endDate) AND User_ID IN ( 
        SELECT User_ID 
        FROM UserClicks
        WHERE (Date BETWEEN monthBeforeStartDate AND startDate)
    ) GROUP BY User_ID
```

Comment: although using BETWEEN works too, and I've switched to using that. =]

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious... why don't you just have a more detailed where statement?

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) AS total

FROM UserClicks

WHERE (Date > :startDate AND Date < :endDate)

AND (Date > :monthBeforeStartDate AND Date < :startDate)`

Update:
It seems like you want a count of the number of users who clicked between startDate and endDate who also clicked in the month before the startDate.

Depending on if your dates are in a MySQL-friendly format (like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), then you can just use MySQL to get the month prior to the start date. Example below:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) AS total

FROM UserClicks

WHERE (Date > :startDate AND Date < :endDate)

AND (Date > DATE_SUB(:startDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND Date < :startDate)`

Comment: having those two where statements makes it so it doesn't return anything. I get zero from that query. I think it's because they can't both be true

Comment: Doh, silly me. Yeah looks like you will need a nested select. Or perhaps another join.

I wonder if this'll achieve the same results as the nested query...

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) AS total FROM UserClicks AS uc1 JOIN UserClicks AS uc2 ON uc2.Date > :monthBeforeStartDate AND uc2.Date < :startDate AND uc1.User_ID = uc2.User_ID WHERE uc1.Date > :startDate AND uc1.Date < :endDate`

Answer (score 0):

I've had a hard time with sub-queries in mysql in which both queries use the same table. My solution has always been to use a join

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT User_ID) AS total
FROM UserClick u1 
    JOIN UserClick u2 
        on u2.User_ID = u1.User_ID
WHERE u1.Date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
    AND u2.Date BETWEEN :monthBeforeStartDate and :startDate
```